# "List ownedDevices" doesn't return all my devices

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I tried this [List ownedDevices](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ownedDevices) API using graph explorer and I don't see all the devices I own. But I do see my desktop when I query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$filter=displayName eq 'mydesktopnamehere'.

Where the user-device mapping defined? Why the list ownedDevices result is incomplete?

Answer (score 1):

There is a relationship between the user who *joined/registered* the device and the device via a corresponding 'owner' attribute. There is one case (the domain joined case) where there is no user as an owner, and this is because domain joined devices automatically register with Azure AD using their own computer accounts (even in the absence of a user logged on).

If you are interested, these are the ways a device is registered with Azure AD:

1. Domain Joined devices registered with Azure AD: This is traditionally domain joined devices (to AD on-premises) that then automatically register with Azure AD. For Windows 10 computers registration happens in the absence of a user so there is no user owner for these computers (the owner is really the computer account on-prem).
2. Azure AD Joined devices: This is when you configure a Windows 10 device from the out-of-box-experience (OOBE) using your Azure AD account. In this case the device gets registered into Azure AD and the user who authenticated in OOBE is added as an owner of the device.
3. Personal device configured with Add Work or School Account: This is when you have your Windows 10 device signing in with you Microsoft account (Hotmail, Live, Xbox, etc.) but then add your Azure AD account to Windows. In this case the device gets registered as well and the Azure AD user account will be the owner of the device.
4. iOS/Android and other platforms we are adding support to require a user to authenticate when adding the account to the device. This registers the device and associate the user as an owner.

For more information you can read about [DJ auto-registration with Azure AD behind the scenes](https://jairocadena.com/2016/01/18/how-domain-join-is-different-in-windows-10-with-azure-ad/) from my blog. You can see other posts about how Azure AD Join works behind the scenes and how authentication works as well.

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: Thanks for the tips David and Adriaan!